# Slowed Data reader in C#

Tags: c#, array, .net

I am writing code to update data in the sample table (i.e. *stbl*) atoms of a video/audio file and found that in my method `UpdateValues` slows down to almost a crawl when executed. The line `values.Add(value)` was determined to be where the greatest time was taken through the debugger. Stepping through the program it was determined to take ~10mS to process. This `List<int>` is not touched by any other portion of the program. No other code appears to affect this list during the process.

```
public byte[] UpdateValues(int offset, string varName)
{
    //Create initial list
    List<int> values = new List<int>();
    //Set initial position to offset from (size, name, flags, count)
    int position = ((varName == "stsz") ? 20 : 16);
    //temporary byte array
    byte[] tempSize = new byte[4];

    //continue until position is equal to length of data
    while (position < this.data.Length)
    {
        //Get value from position
        Array.Copy(this.data, position, tempSize, 0, 4);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)//Check for Endianess
            Array.Reverse(tempSize);//Reverse if necessary

        //update the value to include the new offset
        int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(tempSize, 0) + offset;

        //Add the new value to a list
        values.Add(value);//fixed from 'Values', no change in output time
        //increment the location
        position += 4;
    }

    //Sets the values back to the original location as updated
    return SetValues(values, varName);
}
```

The `SetValues` method is not slow and takes less than a second to complete:

```
public byte[] SetValues( List<int> values, string name )
{
    int location = 0;

    int _size = (values.Count * 4) + ((name == "stsz")? 20 : 16);
    this.data = new byte[_size];
    byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(_size);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(temp);

    //add size into first 4
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, this.data, location, temp.Length);
    location += temp.Length;

    //add box type label
    temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, this.data, location, temp.Length);
    location += temp.Length;

    //add FLAGS
    temp = new byte[(name == "stsz")? 8 : 4];//add 4 bytes of 0 flags and version
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, this.data, location, temp.Length);
    location += temp.Length;

    //add Entry Count
    temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(values.Count);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(temp);
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, this.data, location, temp.Length);
    location += temp.Length;



    //Add list of offsets to total
    foreach (int a in values)
    {
        temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(temp);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, this.data, location, temp.Length);
        location += temp.Length;
    }
    return this.data;
}
```

Comment: @Heslacher Thank you for catching that. I updated the parameter, but am still seeing a major slow down there.

Comment: That is the size of the atom that I am updating, largest I have seen is about 300k

Comment: Just tested these 2 methods with 300000 bytes. In debug mode they finished in 19ms. I guess your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Heslacher It appears it had to do with the `values.Add(value)`, as this was taking about 10mS for each iteration during my testing. I'm not sure what the difference is from mine to your debug sessions is, but have updated it to avoid the entire issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Something else has to be going on.  I should not take 10 ms to add a value to values.

Comment: Could you please add more information as to how you determined that the `values.Add(value)` is the source of the slowdown? Is there other code that surrounds this that modifies `values`?

Comment: @Snowbody I have updated my question with the information you requested. I have also already answered my question by rewriting the method to reduce unnecessary use of the list.

Comment: BTW, using the debugger to time statements is not reliable.

Comment: @Snowbody I agree that they are not reliable, they are good for comparisons of known values. In this instance I wouldn't expect a time higher than <1mS, and this was taking 10mS. Should they all have read as expected, I would have put in a timer to do a proper calc of the failure.

Comment: By "not reliable" I mean the debugger can randomly stall for ~100mS IME completely unrelated to the actual performance of the program. If you really want known values, it's not hard to use [the `Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for reliable timing.

Comment: @Snowbody I will add that in next time I run. Currently the program is running closer to the anticipated values based on the changes made from the accepted answer. Thank you for the experience info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the addition of int to values being the point of slow down, code was adjusted and properly fitted.

The method `UpdateValues` creates a `List<int>` that is later written over the data in the same location through the method `SetValues`. Removing the `List<int>` and simply changing the values in-line with the location it was originally taken from removes the need for the extra call, as well as removes the need for the `List<int>` in the method `UpdateValues`.

```
    public byte[] UpdateValues( int offset, string varName )
    {

        int position = ((varName == "stsz") ? 20 : 16);

        byte[] tempSize = new byte[4];

        //continue until position is equal to length of data
        while (position < this.data.Length)
        {
            //Get value from position
            Array.Copy(this.data, position, tempSize, 0, 4);

            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(tempSize);

            //update the value with the offset given
            int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(tempSize, 0) + offset;

            tempSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(tempSize);

            //write bytes back to same location as read from
            Array.Copy(tempSize, 0, this.data, position, tempSize.Length);

            //Move forward to next size
            position += 4;
        }

        //return the updated data
        return this.data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several Comments that are unnecessary. You should get rid of them, since your code explains a few of those Comments.

Most C# coding standards suggest that you always use braces for `if` statements, so instead of this:

> ```
>  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)//Check for Endianess
>         Array.Reverse(tempSize);//Reverse if necessary
> ```

you would format it like this:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(tempSize);
}
```

Comment: Most comments were added solely for posting to this site. Original code only had 3 comments. I would agree with the braces for the if statements, this was low level code that had not been completed and was being tested. I appreciate the response.

Comment: @vipersassassin Comments should add value to the code by explaining things that are non-obvious, especially WHY the code is doing what it is doing. Comments like "temporary byte array" are obvious from context; the comment should explain what the byte array is used for and why it's needed.